# Controlling resources using concurrent concepts

Tags: java

I am writing Thread based application with 10 threads and maintaining database connection pool of 5 and returning databse transaction after transaction success or failure regardless. Am i require to use Counting semaphore to control the thread access to database connection or  have to use ReentrantLock and its condition object to control the access ? Really confusing these 2 concetps. Please provide any suggestions.

Regards,

Chaituhara

Comment: Are you asking whether any concurrency locking is needed at all, or are you asking which approach is best?

Comment: First whether my code require concurrency,if yes which one to use

Comment: While JDBC is technically thread-safe, it's probably best to have each thread obtain its own Connection from the connection pool.  Then the only place you need to worry about multi-threaded access is the connection pool itself, which a Lock or `synchronized` block will address.